# Number of colors in frame buffer

Tags: graphics

I don't know how to solve this. The main thing I do know how buffers work but I don't know about display locations and lookup tables.

A color frame buffer has 3 bits per display location and 6 bits per entry in three lookup tables. What is total number of colors in the palette from which this frame buffer has to choose?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  It sounds like it would be better to instead ask a conceptual question about display locations or lookup tables (one concept per question, please), after doing some reading and research to learn as much about them as you can on your own.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that.  Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on.

Comment: Also, this might be helpful: http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755

Comment: Palette : 2**(6+6+6)=262144 colours made of 64 levels of blue, 64 levels of red and 64 levels of green. The 3bits per display location makes 8 colours : For each pixel you can pick one of 8 colours, each of these colour is chosen among 262144. You can only have up to 8 different colours in the displayed picture, unless you manage to change on-the-fly the palette in synchronization with the scanning, something which was done sometimes in the 80's in home computers as Ataris, Amigas...

Comment: @TEMLIB -- would you like to write that as an answer, so we can upvote it?